# Динамический ввод в структуру. Гибкий ввод

Tags: c++, структуры, структуры-данных, ввод

Здравствуйте, задался вопросом, как сделать чтобы не указывать сколько элементов вводить, а сколько ввел столько и будет?

```
struct Node{
 string name;
 floar money;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, все равно нужно в какой-то момент как-то дать сигнал остановиться :) - либо закончив ввод закрытием потока ввода (Ctrl-Z в Windows), либо вводя некоторое предопределенное слово, означающее, что ввод завершен. Логично?

Ну, а если вы о том, куда записывать, не зная заранее, сколько будет записай - так берите любой из контейнеров типа `vector`, `list` или там дек.

Я смог ответить на ваш вопрос?

Дополнение с ответом на вопрос в комменте.
Псевдокод ввода с запросом имеет примерно такой вид:

```
do {

    Ввод элемента

    Ввод_еще_одного = Запрос о вводе еще одного элемента();

} while(Ввод_еще_одного == true);
```

Comment: Не полностью, но спасибо. Просто у меня все реализовано на структурах.

Comment: Ну тогда уточните, что осталось за рамками ответа?

Comment: Как правильно сделать следующее: Вводим один элемент, потом спрашивает ли вводить еще или закончить ввод. Сделать через счетчик который увеличивается на 1, если пользователь захотел ввести еще элемент?

Comment: `for(;;){ Ввод элемента. Запрос "Ввести еще?" if(нет) break; }` - примерно так. Счетчик нужен, только если в какой-то массив записывается - текущий индекс. в контейнер - добавлять с помощью `push_back()`.

Comment: @Harry, наверно, стоит дополнить текст ответа.